# Development of Sharepoint Data Entry Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint-2007

I am in the process of developing several data entry forms that the client has asked to be accessible through the SharePoint interface (2007 WSS version).

The forms will, among other requirements, consist of multiple drop downs that have to be loaded from tables in SQL Server. These lists of data are updated frequently through a process that sucks data in from Great Plains.

My inclination is to create a Web Part Page with a Page Viewer Web Part and go full screen like this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/malag/archive/2008/09/15/story-of-a-mischievous-page-viewer-web-part.aspx

...and then to do the pages in ASP.NET MVC3.  Is there a better story than this?  The integrated SP development paradigm seems like waaaay more overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a common issue with developers new the SharePoint paradigm, especially for 2007. The short answer is that your solution will be the quickest way to get to where you want to go but isn't the "cleanest".

The other option is to create a SharePoint Solution and publish an **application page** to the _layouts directory. A quintessential "hello world" example can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb418732(office.12).aspx.

New SP developers will find the hardest transition with deployment. The **WSPBuilder** codeplex project http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/ has become the industries default solution for doing this. An example of using this can be found at http://www.greggalipeau.com/category/sharepoint/wspbuilder/.

For you I would say the key words are **Application Pages** and **WSPBuilder**.

Comment: I disagree: the biggest hurdle for new SP developers is the realization that they must develop **on the server**

Comment: I agree that is a big hurdle. I was able to get past it quicker then the deployment issue but I used a VM and had access to an MSDN subscription at the time. I felt it was more time consuming than "mentally challenging" compared to the deployment process.

Comment: I guess I'm still remembering the horrified look I've seen when telling people I had to install Visual Studio on a Windows Server box, and that I was actually going to be using it through an interactive login, and that, yes, they should probably buy a Server license just for developers. Unusual for any other development platform.

Comment: Okay...so I get that paradigm, and thank you for the comments.  But I can't control the source of the data in this case (an SQL server separate from the WSS box). I get integrated authentication for free already in ASP.NET MVC, and building the foundation for the pages is a snap with MvcScaffolding. Forgive the questions here...there are a lot of voices into SP dev and it's hard to collate the proper stack. The 2010 kit seems a lot more dev-friendly. I understand my solution above may not be the clean "SharePoint" way to do things, but is there something *wrong* with it?

Comment: Wrong: I guess I don't inherit the SP services and direct access that you'd get through application pages.  There are no requirements on the table at this point for those kinds of things, but I know that's a cost in the way I'm doing it.

Comment: Btw...I'm accepting this as the answer and appreciate your help but would love to keep the conversation going if you're interested.

Comment: Glad to keep it going, I don't see anything wrong with what you are doing. It could be argued that is what the page viewer web part was designed for. If you need to access SP data from outside of SP you can always use web services. They are a pretty robust subset of what you can do in the object model (what you use in the application page).